# Using TCP Receive Buffer as a Buffer for Multimedia Applications

Tags: tcp, streaming

Is it possible to use the TCP receive buffer to buffer data in multimedia streaming applications? What are the respective reasons?

Answer (score 0):

> Is it possible to use the TCP receive buffer to buffer data

Yes.

> in multimedia streaming applications?

In any applications. That's what a buffer is for. To buffer data.

> What are the respective reasons?

Reasons for what?